# Finding Means with arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, mean

I got the assignment and the numbers to create a program which asks

> You are to write a C++ program that will prompt for and re ad in the
>   Math and Verbal SAT scores for a sample population of students and
>   then determine the mean Math SAT score, the mean Verbal SAT score, the
>   standard deviation for the Math SAT scores and the standard deviation
>   for the Verbal SAT scores respectively.

The part that is confusing me is I am not sure if the program is asking me to input the scores given right into the code or to make a function or whatever to input them in as a user.

This another part of the assignment which may be pertinent.

> Read the Math and Verbal SAT scores from the keyboard into a two
>   dimensional array for storage. The array should have 10rows and two
>   columns one for the math SAT score and the second for the verbal SAT
>   score.

Sorry for asking such an easy question my brain is fried and I am in over my head. I am going in for help tomorrow but I need to have more of a code together because the project is due for Wednesday.

Comment: This is very hard to read as it stands. You need to break it up into paragraphs, explain what the problem is, and show what you've tried already (i.e., show us some code).

Comment: What exactly is the question? Are you asking "does this project say the application should accept user input or use hardcoded values"? If so, go with user-input (it's always the correct approach for school projects). If not, what's the question (and what have you tried)?

Comment: "program that will prompt for and re ad in the Math and Verbal SAT scores": this means the program will take the scores as input at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

> write a C++ program that will prompt for and re ad in the Math and Verbal SAT scores

You're expected to take them as input from the user.

i.e. don't hardcode them, take them as keyboard input.